# How to pause and resume a simple game in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener, java-3d

i made simple game by java , it's about "tennis background" and "tennis ball" , and the ball is randomally move automatically ,

my game consist of two file , 1st file fore Jpanel , and 2nd file for JFrame ,

my question is : i need to control of "stopping and resuming" the ball by clicking the mouse , 
i tried to put wait() during thread running loop , but it's faild , i don't know what is the reason ! , so please review my code and then tell me what is the wrong , and what is the true method of "pause&resume" thread in my simple game !

tennis.java file (which contain the thread):

```
/*
 * tennis.java
 *
 * Created on Nov 15, 2011, 3:35:28 PM
 */
package io;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class tennis extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable{

    BufferedImage ball;
    BufferedImage bg;
    int ball_h = 0;
    int ball_w = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int width  = 0;
    int yPos   = -1;
    int xPos   = 10;
    int pause  = 20;

    // Move Speed
    int xMov   = 5;
    int yMov   = 10;
    boolean clicked = false;
    int play    =   0;

    Thread runner;

    /** Creates new form tennis */
    public tennis() throws IOException {

        ball = ImageIO.read(new File("tennis/ball.png"));
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File("tennis/bg.jpg"));
        ball_h = 50;
        ball_w = 50;
        height = 600 - ball_h;
        width  = 800  - ball_w;

        runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.start();

    }

    public void start(){
       if(play == 0){

           play     =   1;
           clicked = true;

       }else{
           play    =  0;
           clicked = true;
       }

       System.out.println(play);
    }

    public void stop(){
        runner = null;
    }




    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2D  =   (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 800,600, this);
        g2D.drawImage(ball, xPos, yPos,50,50, this);
    }


    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(runner == runner){



                    if(xPos >= (width))
                        {
                           xMov   *= -1;   
                        }



                           xPos   += xMov;

                    if(xPos < 1)
                        {
                           xMov   *= -1;   
                        }                

                    if(yPos >= (height-ball_h))
                        {
                            yMov    *= -1 ;
                        }



                            yPos    += yMov;

                     if(yPos < 1)
                        {
                            yMov    *= -1 ;
                        }

                    repaint();



                    try {
                        if(play == 1){
                            Thread.sleep(pause);
                        }else{
                            synchronized(this){
                                while(play == 0){
                                wait();
                              }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(tennis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

        }  
    }

}
```

Tennis3D.java file(frame for starting the game and define the thread) :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Tennis3D.java
 *
 * Created on Nov 15, 2011, 3:42:42 PM
 */
package io;

import io.tennis;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Tennis3D extends javax.swing.JFrame implements MouseListener{

    tennis tennis;

    /** Creates new form Tennis3D */
    public Tennis3D() {
        super("Tennis3D");
        setSize(800,600);


        try {
            tennis = new tennis();
            add(tennis);
            tennis.addMouseListener(this);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tennis3D.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        setVisible(true);

    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Tennis3D tennis = new Tennis3D();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       tennis.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: one way is to have an update() method which moves the game objects based on how much time has passed since it was last called.  then in the top of the update method, you check a flag used to indicate the game is paused.  if the game is paused, just return and don't do any updating.

Comment: >while(runner == runner)?? Do you mean while(true)?

Comment: `int play = 1` - why aren't you using a `boolean` for this?  And please seperate your display code from your 'model' (the tennis ball) code, it'll make future work much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is piggy-backing on what Nerdtron wrote in the comment above.  Typically a game loop looks like this

```
 while (!game.isOver())
 {
      if (!game.isPaused())
           game.update()  // this moves your ball, players, etc
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is strange. Most games have a sort of main loop where methods update(deltaTime) and draw() are called sequentially.

Typical main loop:

```
initGame();
while(!gameOver)
{
    readInput();
    update(deltaTime);
    draw();
}
```

update(dt) is something like

```
for(GameObject go : myObjectList)
{
    go.update(deltaTime);
}
```

If you want to skip some objects you could use something like:

```
for(GameObject go : myObjectList)
{
    if(go.isActive())
    {
        go.update(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

So your task would be trivial if you use game-loop structure like that.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a thread wait()ing you need to call notifyAll() on the same object.

From the Javadoc for Object.wait()

> Causes current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

I would suggest you call notifyAll() in a synchronized block when you set `play = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

A common way to achieve this is by using different states. So when you would put the game on pause it would go in `PAUSE` state. When resumed it would go back in `RUNNING` state or some other (more specific) state.
This is done by keeping the state in a variable. The `C`-way is to define integers like follows:

```
final int PAUSE = 1;
final int RUNNING = 2;
```

The `Java`-way is more like this: (using `enum`s)

```
public enum State {
    RUNNING,
    PAUSE
}
```

Then, in your main loop (`run` method) you check the state in which the game is at that moment, and perform actions accordingly.

```
switch(state){
    case PAUSE:
        Thread.sleep(100);
        break;
    case RUNNING:
        // do something entertaining
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so, if youre game loop includes a tick method or a particular method that updates the values of all the game objects, you can make a boolean called aused and only update the game values only if !paused.

And you can also use a class that extends Mouse adapter and add a mouselistener to your main class. so whenever the mouse clicked it checks if it is paused of not. if paused it unpauses it, if unpause then it pauses it