# Pause game thread while separate JFrame is open

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, sleep

I am making a game in java and I am trying to make my pause menu. At the moment I am checking for the esc button being pressed and running my menu JFrame. The problem is that my game keeps running in the background. How would I pause the game thread while the menu is open?

Code for main game loop

```
public void run() {
    try {
        init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
    double ns = 1000000000/amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta +=(now - lastTime)/ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        render();
    }
    stop();
}
```

Code for checking for pause menu

```
public void tick() {

    if (up) {

        playerUp = true;
        playerDown = false;
        playerLeft = false;
        playerRight = false;
        y -= SPEED;
        moving = true;
    }
    if (dn) {
        playerDown = true;
        playerLeft = false;
        playerRight = false;
        playerUp = false;
        y += SPEED;
        moving = true;
    }
    if (lt) {

        playerLeft = true;
        playerRight = false;
        playerDown = false;
        playerUp = false;
        x -= SPEED;
        moving = true;
    }
    if (rt) {
        playerRight = true;
        playerLeft = false;
        playerUp = false;
        playerDown = false;
        x += SPEED;
        moving = true;
    }


    if (esc) {
        pauseMenu.main(null);
    }
```

Comment: Please share a sample code.

Comment: look here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299010/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-simple-game-in-java for a little sample ... if not helps show some of your code

Comment: edited question with code included

Answer (score 0):

A couple hints:

`tick()` is where you are running your game's code, but it shouldn't decide when to tick - because if it becomes paused, how does it unpause itself?

You are already limiting the number of times you call `tick()`. Essentially, you want to limit it even more when your game becomes "paused."